# Define-Produce function from a loop?

Tags: function-construction, programming, syntax

Consider the following code:

```
L = 4;
sind = Range[-π, (2 π/L)*(L/2 - 1), 2 π/L]
Clear[len]; len = Length[sind];
ix1 = Flatten[Table[sind[[i]], {i, len}, len]]
iy1 = Flatten[Table[Table[sind[[i]], {i, 1, len}], len]]

(* sind={-π, -(π/2), 0, π/2} 
  ix1={-π, -π, -π, -π, -(π/2), -(π/2), -(π/2), -(π/2), 0, 0, 0, 0, π/2, π/2, π/2, π/2}
  iy1={-π, -(π/2), 0, π/2, -π, -(π/2), 0, π/2, -π, -(π/2), 0, π/2, -π, -(π/2), 0, π/2} *)
```

Now we do a loop over the elements of `ix1,iy1` in order to evaluate `jnum`:

```
k = 0;
For[i = 1, i <= Length[ix1], i += len, For[j = 1, j <= len, j++,
 jnum = k len + Mod[j, len + 1];
Print[i, " , ", j, " , ", ix1[[i]], " , ", iy1[[j]], " , ", jnum]
]; k = k + 1;]

(*  1 , 1 , -π , -π , 1
    1 , 2 , -π , -(π/2) , 2
    1 , 3 , -π , 0 , 3
    1 , 4 , -π , π/2 , 4
    5 , 1 , -(π/2) , -π , 5
    5 , 2 , -(π/2) , -(π/2) , 6
    5 , 3 , -(π/2) , 0 , 7
    5 , 4 , -(π/2) , π/2 , 8
    9 , 1 , 0 , -π , 9
    9 , 2 , 0 , -(π/2) , 10
    9 , 3 , 0 , 0 , 11
    9 , 4 , 0 , π/2 , 12
   13 , 1 , π/2 , -π , 13
   13 , 2 , π/2 , -(π/2) , 14
   13 , 3 , π/2 , 0 , 15
   13 , 4 , π/2 , π/2 , 16 *)
```

I want to create a function `f`: `f[-π ,-π]=1, f[-π ,-(π/2)]=2, ...,f[π/2,π/2] = 16`, i.e I need the `x`, `y` arguments of `f[x_,y_]` be given by the third and fourth columns and the output be the last column (which is given by `jnum` inside the loop).
A piecewise definition for every `x,y` pair is obviously not the answer. Can it be done using `Block` or `Module`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of printing the data, we create a list `dat`, whereby we only need columns 3..5. Then we map an expression that defines our function `fun` onto the list elements:

```
L = 4;
sind = Range[-\[Pi], (2 \[Pi]/L)*(L/2 - 1), 2 \[Pi]/L];
Clear[len]; len = Length[sind];
ix1 = Flatten[Table[sind[[i]], {i, len}, len]];
iy1 = Flatten[Table[Table[sind[[i]], {i, 1, len}], len]];

k = 0;
dat = Reap[
    For[i = 1, i <= Length[ix1], i += len, 
     For[j = 1, j <= len, j++, jnum = k len + Mod[j, len + 1];
      Sow[{ix1[[i]], iy1[[j]], jnum}]
      ]; k = k + 1;]
    ][[2, 1]];

Clear[fun];
(fun[#1, #2] = #3) & @@@ dat;
?? fun
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

Daniel's answer using `Reap` and `Sow` is better. An alternative to `Reap` and `Sow` is what I was working with and it is the following:

```
 R1 = {};
 For[i = 1, i <= len, i++, a = sind[[i]];
 For[j = 1, j <= len, j++, b = sind[[j]]; R = {}; R = {a, b}; 
R1 = Append[R1, R]];
 ];
R1
(*=> {{-π, -π}, {-π, -(π/2)}, {-π, 0}, {-π, π/2}, {-(π/2), -π}, 
{-(π/2), -(π/2)}, {-(π/2), 0}, {-(π/2), π/2}, {0, -π}, {0, -(π/2)}, {0, 0}, 
{0, π/2}, {π/2, -π}, {π/2, -(π/2)}, {π/2, 0}, {π/2, π/2}} *)

k = 0; R2 = {};
For[i = 1, i <= Length[R1], i++, k = k + 1; R = {}; R = {R1[[i]], k}; 
R = Flatten[R, 2]; R2 = Append[R2, R]]
R2

(*=> {{-π, -π, 1}, {-π, -(π/2), 2}, {-π, 0, 3}, {-π, π/2, 4}, 
(π/2), -π, 5},  {-(π/2), -(π/2), 6}, {-(π/2), 0, 7}, {-(π/2), π/2, 8}, 
{0, -π, 9}, {0, -(π/2), 10}, {0, 0, 11}, {0, π/2, 12}, {π/2, -π, 13}, 
{π/2, -(π/2), 14}, {π/2, 0, 15}, {π/2, π/2, 16}} *)
```

and then you define the function as in Daniel's answer

```
Clear[fun];
(fun[#1, #2] = #3) & @@@ R2;
?? fun
```